# How to add new row to streamlit-aggrid when click the a button?

Tags: javascript, python, ag-grid

I am using the JavaScript based AG-GRID library while writing a web application with python. I am trying to add new rows into the table directly from the app.

I need to run some javascript code from within python. But I can't do this when I click the button. Thanks in advance for your help. Is there anything else I need to do to run JavaScript code inside the button's click event?
My codes are below.

```
import streamlit as st
from st_aggrid import AgGrid, GridUpdateMode
from st_aggrid.grid_options_builder import GridOptionsBuilder
from st_aggrid.shared import JsCode

df = pd.read_csv("data/collabs.csv")
st.dataframe(df)

gd= GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(df)
gd.configure_pagination(enabled=True)
gd.configure_default_column(editable=True, groupable=True)

_radio = st.sidebar.radio(label="Functions", options = ['Radio_Add', 'Update'])

add_button = st.sidebar.button("Add New Row")

if _radio == 'Radio_Add':
    js = JsCode("""
    function(e) {
        let api = e.api;
        let rowData = [
                { CollaboratorName: "Toyota", Location: "Celica", HourlyRate: 35000 },
                { CollaboratorName: "sdsdsd", Location: "dsd", HourlyRate: 22 },
                { CollaboratorName: "uslu", Location: "ii", HourlyRate: 90 }
                ];
        api.applyTransaction({add: rowData})    
    };
    """)
    gd.configure_selection(selection_mode='single', use_checkbox=True)
    gridOptions = gd.build(onRowSelected=js)
    grid_table = AgGrid(df,
                        gridOptions=gridOptions,
                        fit_columns_on_grid_load=True,
                        height=500,
                        width='100%',
                        theme="streamlit",
                        update_mode=GridUpdateMode.SELECTION_CHANGED,
                        reload_data=False,
                        allow_unsafe_jscode=True,
                        )
```

**When I click the radio button, the add process is done, but when I click the button, I cannot.**

```
if add_button:
    js = JsCode("""
    function(e) {
        let api = e.api;
        let rowData = [
                { CollaboratorName: "Toyota", Location: "Celica", HourlyRate: 35000 },
                { CollaboratorName: "sdsdsd", Location: "dsd", HourlyRate: 22 },
                { CollaboratorName: "uslu", Location: "ii", HourlyRate: 90 }
                ];
        api.applyTransaction({add: rowData})    
    };
    """
             )

    gd.configure_grid_options(pre_selected_rows=[])
    gridOptions = gd.build()
    grid_table = AgGrid(df,
                        gridOptions=gridOptions,
                        #enable_enterprise_modules=True,
                        fit_columns_on_grid_load=True,
                        height=500,
                        width='100%',
                        theme="streamlit",
                        update_mode=GridUpdateMode.GRID_CHANGED,
                        reload_data=False,
                        allow_unsafe_jscode=True,
                        )
```